# Multiprocessing between local machine and AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, multiprocessing, ipc

I developed 3 scripts (a Server, a Writer and a Reader) that work together using BaseManager from multiprocessing.managers. All of them run fine together in AWS or locally. But now I want to mix things up. For more complex scripts, using GPU, I want to use my local machine, and still run it off of AWS...

How do I connect to "the Server", who creates the IPC, the queues etc, which is running on AWS?

(Edit: I found the anwser, please see below, I removed the technical details I had previously left on here and created a more generic question and answer for those of you who have the same issue)

Please see the code for the 3 entities below:

The Server:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from queue import Queue

class Server():
    def __init__(self, ip, port, authkey):
        super(Server, self).__init__()
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.authkey = authkey

    def make_server_manager(self):
        """ Create a manager for the server, listening on the given port.
            Return a manager object with all the required queues.
        """
        q = Queue()  # input queue
        BaseManager.register('q', callable=lambda: q)
        manager = BaseManager(address=(self.ip, self.port), authkey=self.authkey)
        print('Server started at port ' + str(self.port))
        return manager


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip = '172.31.2.45'
    port = 11111
    authkey = 'abc'.encode('utf-8')

    s = Server(ip, port, authkey)
    mgr = s.make_server_manager()
    s = mgr.get_server()
    s.serve_forever()
```

The Writer (running on AWS, though that might also run locally on my machine if I need it to):

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class Client():

    def __init__(self, ip, port, authkey):
        super(Client, self).__init__()
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.authkey = authkey

        # Create the queus and variables
        BaseManager.register('q')
        m = BaseManager(address=(ip, port), authkey=authkey)
        m.connect()
        self.q = m.q()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip = '172.31.2.45'
    port = 11111
    authkey = 'abc'.encode('utf-8')

    Client = Client(ip, port, authkey)

    while True:
        X = input('What is your secret message?')
        Client.q.put(X)
        if X == 'Close':
            break
```

The reader (Running on my local machine for the purpose of this exercise)

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class Client():

    def __init__(self, ip, port, authkey):
        super(Client, self).__init__()
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.authkey = authkey

        # Create the queus and variables
        BaseManager.register('q')
        m = BaseManager(address=(ip, port), authkey=authkey)
        print('connecting...')
        m.connect()
        print('connected')
        self.q = m.q()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip = '18.191.25.217'
    port = 11111
    authkey = 'abc'.encode('utf-8')

    Client = Client(ip, port, authkey)

    while True:
        rcvd = Client.q.get()
        print(rcvd)
        if rcvd == 'Close':
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I found the answer myself, so decided to modify my question a bit and made sure I highlight the important bits in the answer.)

In order for this to work, it's important to set up the IP addresses properly in your security group on AWS and in your scripts.

The answer I give here assumes that the **Server runs on AWS**, and other scripts can be run either locally or AWS.

You need the following set up:
In your AWS security group create a custom TCP Rule with the following specifications:
1. IP Address: The IP address of your local machine
2. Port Range: The port (range / number) on which you Server runs, in this case 11111

Your scripts must contain the following IP addresses:
 - Server (running on AWS): The private IP of the instance on AWS
 - Processes not running on AWS (Reader / Writer / Whatever you choose to run on your local machine): The public IPv4 address of the instance on which the Server is running

The port number and authentication code in your scripts must obviously all be matching.

Hope it's clear. Enjoy everyone.